# How to correctly setup Spring Boot 2.2 REST full integration test with JUnit5

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have simple controller, facade, set of services and repository for my H2 DB for Customer entity. It works fine but I need an E2E integration test with whole application context. And with JUnit5.

I've tried many setups, many times got errors like `found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test`. Finally I made it work, but there is an issue with Spring JPA CustomerRepository which is an interface. I've never tried to use it like this so I have no experiance with it. But simply speaking, it won't create any bean of this type since it's just an interface. As the spring boot application, it works this way, but in the integration test it won't.

The error is still the same: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [xxx.CustomerRepository]`.

This is my test setup:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    CustomerController.class,
    CustomerFacade.class,
    CustomerTerminationService.class,
    CustomerRepository.class
})
@WebMvcTest(CustomerController.class)
@Import(CustomerRepository.class)
class CustomerFullIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void getCustomer() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .get("/customer/1")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName").exists())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.products").isNotEmpty());
    }
}
```

This is my repository:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {}
```

This is my Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProfApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller, facade, services are irrelevant.

Can you tell me, what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `@SpringBootTest` combined with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` clashes with `@WebMvcTest` over `found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith`. And if I delete `@WebMvcTest`, I get the same `BeanInstantiationException`.

Comment: What do want to test exactly ? complete end to end integration? or just controller layer ? @JiKra

Comment: Complete e2e integration. It's a simple SpringBoot 2.2 application with SpringData and H2, JUnit5 etc.

Comment: @JiKra Can you please update your question with spring-boot main class?